# Why is my Flex as3 crossdomain.xml not working?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, azure

I have spent so much time trying to figure out what is going wrong with my crossdomain.xml implementation. There are tons of questions here about them and I have tried everything from every question.

I am using Azure Blob Storage to store images that my swf needs to access. Also I am using the BulkLoader swc to load in these assets. Below is code that runs before the application attempts to load images from the url.

```
Security.allowDomain("mydomain.blob.core.windows.net");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("mydomain.blob.core.windows.net");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://mydomain.blob.core.windows.net/crossdomain.xml");
```

Here is a sample of different crossdomain.xml configurations I have tried. I've probably tried 20 different configurations and nothing seems to work.

1.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all" />
  <allow-access-from domain="*" />
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

2.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only" />
  <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

3.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

This is the error I get in the flashlog file.

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'http://localhost:81/controller/view' tried to access incompatible
context 'http://mydomain.blob.core.windows.net/crossdomain.xml'
```

Any help would be appreciated. This problem is driving me crazy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a guess, but can you check the ACL of `$root` container containing this crossdomain.xml file? It should be either `Blob` or `Public`.

Comment: Yes the $root container is set to Blob. I can load the crossdomain.xml in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what I was doing wrong. You need to send bulkLoader a LoaderContext just like you do to the normal Loader class. Here is the code I've used. Also use a SoundLoaderContext when loading a sound file.

```
var currentSecurityDomain:SecurityDomain = null;
if (Security.sandboxType == Security.REMOTE)
    currentSecurityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;

var loaderContext = new LoaderContext(true, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, currentSecurityDomain);

var currentSecurityDomain:SecurityDomain = null;
if (Security.sandboxType == Security.REMOTE)
    currentSecurityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;

var soundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(1000, true);

var currentSecurityDomain:SecurityDomain = null;
if (Security.sandboxType == Security.REMOTE)
    currentSecurityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;

var loaderContext = new LoaderContext(true, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, currentSecurityDomain);
var soundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(1000, true);

var bulkLoader:BulkLoader = new BulkLoader("main");
bulkLoader.add(URL, { context: loaderContext, "id":animationID, maxTries:1, priority:priority});
bulkLoader.add(URL_TO_SOUND, { context: soundLoaderContext, "id":animationID, maxTries:1, priority:priority});
bulkLoader.addEventListener(BulkLoader.COMPLETE, onAllItemsLoaded);
bulkLoader.start();
```