# Connecting Flash to Node via websockets - Crossdomain.xml issue

Tags: node.js, actionscript-3, flash, heroku, cross-domain

I am trying to set up a simple websocket server that communicates between a Flash AS3 client and a Node.js backend. The following code is when both the client and server are hosted locally. The code also functions properly when the swf is hosted locally connected to the server hosted on heroku. The socket only fails when both the swf and the server are hosted online.

Node.js Code (Server)

```
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server
var net = require('net');
var http = require("http")
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
var crossdomain = require('crossdomain')
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"))
var xml = crossdomain({ domain: '*' });


app.all('/crossdomain.xml', function (req, res, next) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-8' });
  res.write(xml);
  //res.write(new Buffer([0x00]))
  res.end();
});


var server1 = http.createServer(app)
server1.listen(port)

console.log("http server listening on " + port)

var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server1})

wss.on("connection", function(ws) {
  console.log("Connected");

  ws.on("close", function() {
    console.log("websocket connection close")
  })
})
```

Crossdomain file - example.com/crossdomain.xml

```
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

AS3 Code (Client) - I'm Using (https://github.com/theturtle32/AS3WebSocket)

```
import com.worlize.websocket.*;
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://example.com/crossdomain.xml");
var websocket:WebSocket = new WebSocket("ws://example.com", "*", "echo-protocol");

websocket.addEventListener(WebSocketEvent.OPEN, handleWebSocketOpen);
websocket.connect();

var con = false;

function handleWebSocketOpen(event:WebSocketEvent):void {
  trace(event);
}
```

When the client is accessed from the server a request for the crossdomain.xml does occur and it gets returned successfully to the client, but at that point nothing happens anymore. I've been trying to solve this for ages with no luck. I did find that when you return the crossdomain file you need to end it with a 0x00 for it to be properly read, but I haven't found a way to make to that work. I've tried adding res.write(new Buffer([0x00])) to the response from the crossdomain request as well as several other modifications to no avail. These all seem to stop the xml file from being valid anyway.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could help in getting this to work, I've been struggling with it for an extremely long time and can't quite seem to get this last step working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Flex as3 crossdomain.xml not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676092/why-is-my-flex-as3-crossdomain-xml-not-working)